# Is the verb "wish" correct here?

Tags: formality, email, letter-writing

I'm writing the following sentence and I want to know whether *wish* is the right word or not. When I reading it to myself it doesn't sound good. Since I'm writing this to a professor I don't want to make a bad impression on him.

> I wish I am qualified enough to be accepted in the *** University and your research team.

Is there a better word than *wish* in that sentence?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Frankly I'd be hesitant to point out any uncertainty regarding your qualifications for the role. As you used it, ***wish*** heavily implies that you are not presently qualified, and are relying on the good graces of the professor to help you out.

As was mentioned, **hope** is a very apt choice of word here, but I'd go further and restructure the message like so:

> I hope to have the opportunity to study at ____ University, and a chance to prove myself and make a meaningful contribution to your research team.

It removes any implication that you have doubts about your personal qualifications, whilst simultaneously not appearing as if you *expect* to receive the role.

Answer (score 1):

I think it depends. Do you wish that you would become qualified to be accepted into that university? Or are you qualified enough to be accepted, yet you hope that you are one of the people who become accepted?

I do not know the background, but I will estimate what the background is. I might write the following: "I have demonstrated that I am qualified enough to be accepted in the *** University, and it would mean the world to me if I were accepted so I can become a part of the university as well as your research team."

Answer (score 1):

"I *hope* I am qualified enough to be accepted in the *** University and your research team."

**Hope**. *v*.

*: to want something to happen or be true and think that it could happen or be true*

http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hope

Answer (score 1):

I guess that this *wish* is actually expressing a *hope*.

The tag info for [wish-preterite](/questions/tagged/wish-preterite) on this site says

> for questions using "wish" to express a hypothetical (imaginary) situation or to express regret about a past action that did not happen

This is the standard use of *wish*: it expresses a desire for something which is not yet the case, but might become so — which is what the "hypothetical (imaginary)" is referring to. A situation you wish for is only in your imagination, it's not real yet at all.

That is, "I wish I might be qualified" means that currently you aren't, but want to become qualified. Your qualifications will change if the wish is granted.

However, in your situation, it appears you already have a qualification (which may or may not be sufficient), and the wish won't change that. What you are doing is expressing the *hope* that the qualification is sufficient: that is what you want to be the case.

> [ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/hope) on *hope:*
>
> Want something to happen or be the case:
> [with clause]: I hope that the kids are OK

Your word *wish* should be *hope.*